# How to show currently mapped drives in PowerShell?

Tags: command-line, powershell, .net-framework, c#, mapped-drive

Need a PowerShell command to display drive letter and path it is mapped to.

In other words a command that shows me the same thing Windows Explorer would.

Tried this:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_MappedLogicalDisk | select Name, ProviderName
```

and it is missing several drives (listed in Windows Explorer).

Comment: Does `Get-PSDrive` show these missing drives?  Is there something special or weird about these drives that are missing?  Are they all mappings to a Windows server?

Comment: Do you specifically wish to exclude local filesystem drives?

Comment: How about a good old `NET USE` command from Powershell or a command prompt?

Comment: @ITSolutions `net use` doesn't work in Powershell... unless you drop into cmd prompt

Comment: @Zoredache I can see the missing drive letters under the name column for `Get-PSDrive` command. The provider isn't showing me the path to them. Tried to select the `ProviderName` from `Get-PSDrive` and no dice

Comment: What do you mean 'net use` doesn't work under powershell?  It works perfectly fine.  Perhaps you should spend some type in your question elaborating about why you need this, and how these particular drives were mapped in the first place.  Additional context may help us figure out what the problem is and get you an answer.

Comment: Instead of *mentioning* what you see it would be far mor helpfull to actually *show* what you see. Post a screenshot of your explorer window and the output of `Get-PSDrive`.

Comment: @Zoredache Ok. `net use` worked. I can swear I tried that before and it did not work. I think this is because I was trying to map a network drive last time I used `net use`.

Comment: You won't see mapped network drive in PS or CMD when you run as Administrator

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In PowerShell 5 (Windows 10) and above, use:

```
Get-SMBMapping
```

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/smbshare/get-smbmapping?view=win10-ps

Comment: I'm going to accept this as the answer because this most directly answers the question (e.g. using powershell Cmdlets)

Answer (score 4):

On the assumption that you do *not* wish to exclude drives that point to the local filesystem, I believe that

```
Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem | Select-Object name, @{n="Root"; e={if ($_.DisplayRoot -eq $null) {$_.Root} else {$_.DisplayRoot}}}
```

will serve your need. If you *do* wish to exclude drives that point to the local filesystem, you may find

```
Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem | Select-Object Name, DisplayRoot | Where-Object {$_.DisplayRoot -ne $null}
```

to be more to your liking.

Answer (score 3):

**Try[`NET USE`](http://ss64.com/nt/net-use.html) command from Powershell**

> Ok. net use worked. I can swear I tried that before and it did not
>   work. I think this is because I was trying to map a network drive last
>   time I used net use. – [Kolob
>   Canyon](https://superuser.com/users/503444/kolob-canyon)